# 401 error when trying to GET to OWIN SelfHost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, windows-authentication, credentials, http-status-code-401

I try to GET query from MVC app to OWIN SelfHost. Both have WindowsAuth. MVC is running from Visual Studio in one virtual machine, OWIN SelfHost works as service in other virtual machine. Response is always 401. I tried to set Credentials,PreAuthenticate in WebRequest - nothing changed. I can't let anonymous auth in my system. How I should make request? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found:

```
  WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Properties.Settings.Default.SelfHostAdress + "/api/data/GetReportsOrgStructTreeView?currentUserName=" + currentUsername + "&parentNodeId=" + parentNodeId + "&filterId=" + filterId);
                req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                req.PreAuthenticate = true;
                WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return content;
```